# Find the value for the address in GDB (Cent OS 6)

Tags: linux, gdb

For analysis purpose we want to know the which data(message) is stored in the address. Is there any option to find the message in GDB.

In the other words we know the address (0x80488b4) of memory but we want also know the message stored in that address through GDB.

**Sample code :**

```
(gdb) print option_value
$1 = (const void *) 0x80488b4
```

Comment: What language is the program written in?  If it's object-oriented then please provide a clue to their inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the type `typemsg_t`of the message, you could dereference it, e.g. `print *(typemsg_t*) option_value`

You might also be interested by the GDB [watchpoint](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html) ability.

It is worth taking some time to read [GDB documentation](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/) !

Answer (score 0):

What is "the message"? You can of course examine the contents of memory at that address, using gdb's [x (for examine) command](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_56.html):

```
(gdb) x option_value
```

If you know that `option_value`, despite looking like a `const void *` in the current scope, is really of some other type, you can cast and dereference:

```
(gdb) print *(MessageType *) option_value
```